# Scheme Factorial

Tags: scheme, factorial, cons

I know you can write a simple factorial function by doing this:

```
(define fact
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0) 1
        (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

However, that will only work if you send in a number; it will error if you send in a list or symbol.  So what I want to do is make it work for everything and, if a list, do the factorial of each individual element in the list.  Here is what I have:

```
(define listFact
 (lambda (n)
   (cond
     ((null? n) 1)
     ((symbol? n) n)
     ((number? n) (if (= n 0) 1 (* n (listFact (- n 1)))))
     ((cons? n) (cons (listFact(car n)) (listFact(cdr n)))))))
```

I'm not too great at Scheme, but I need to be able to know the basics.  Every input works properly except for a list.

```
> (listFact '())
```

1

> (listFact 'a)

'a

> (listFact 4)

24

> (listFact '(1 2 3))

cons: second argument must be a list, but received 6 and 1

What I want that last one to do is return:

(list  1 2 6)

I have no idea why it won't work.  If anyone could help me figure this one out without changing the entire structure of the code (i.e. don't use apply/map or multiple functions), it would be much appreciated.  I'd assume the only line messed up is the one with cons.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your implementation of Scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
(cond
     ((null? n) 1)
```

with

```
(cond
     ((null? n) n)
```

for `cons` to work properly, because of the trailing `nil`: a list `(1 2 3)` is actually `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`, so you eventually get to the sentinel `nil` in the end of the list. To reconstruct the list back, you need it to remain an empty list, or `nil`, so that `(cons 6 nil)` creates a new *list* `(6)`; `(cons 6 1)` would create a pair `(6 . 1)` but apparently it doesn't work in your implementation for some reason.

If you want your `()` *elements* in a list to be transformed into `1`s, you will have to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: see updated answer. still have questions? do ask! :)

Comment: whole* post.  But that makes since. Thanks a ton! It was getting rather frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem :

```
((null? n) 1)
```

So, when you try to get the value of an empty list, you get an integer, which is not a list. When your call your function with a list, you get something like that :

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 6 1)))
```

This doesn't work. In order to fix your function, you should try this :

```
((null? n) n)
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize you needed an empty list at the end, considering it is never shown